# What is the Scale of the Minecraft Skin Overlay?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making 3D Minecraft art, and I wanted to have the overlay skin be in accurate proportion to the skin itself.  Does anyone know what the scale of the skin overlay is in comparison to the skin?

Also if this is the wrong place to post this question, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The player is 1.8 blocks tall, which I assume does not include any head-overlay pixels (the default skins do not have overlays). The player's head is 8 pixels tall (in Java Edition; Bedrock edition allows double resolution skins), and the torso and legs are each 12 pixels tall, for a total of 32 pixels.

Assuming that one block is one meter, this would put each base-layer pixel at 1.8 m / 32 = 56.25 mm. For the overlay layer, the wiki [says](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Skin#Properties) this:

> Pixel size of the 2nd layer on body, arms and legs is 0.25 pixel bigger than the skin pixel (inner layer). For head 2nd layer (Hat layer) it is 0.5 pixels bigger than the skin layer (inner layer).

That means the head overlay pixels would be 56.25 mm * 1.5 = 84.375 mm, and the rest of the body's overlay pixels would be 56.25 mm * 1.25 = 70.3125 mm. If your art is not 1:1, you can scale all these numbers up or down as needed.